# how to define our own price tier in itunes connect for inapp content?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes

I just want to knwo that can i modifiy the price tier for inapp content in itunes connect. As we know that there is a list of price tier like $ 0.99, $ 1.99 and so on. I want to price tier like $1.45, $2.50 etc.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can only use the price tiers apple provides you.

Comment: are you sure? is there no any way to do this?

Comment: i am sure. You could try to make a special deal with apple, but i seriously doubt there is any chance of success.

Answer (score 0):

check all of the pricing on iTunes stores - its all about simplicity.
they only have 3 price tiers for songs(.69 & .99. & 1.29) and the other items are all 99 cent increments. possibly related to credit card fee's too